# ¿ThreadPoolExecutor está mezclando los datos de entrada con la función en cada subproceso? Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, hilos

El código que presento a continuación (Python 3.6.12 -Windows x64) tiene como propósito calcular el flujo de potencia en un sistema eléctrico que recibe como parámetro la potencia eléctrica de una carga y la red. A través de los threads pretendo ejecutar la función para diferentes valores de carga, sin embargo la respuesta no es correcta porque los datos correspondientes a ciertos valores de P [0,10,20,30,40,50] están escritos en varios resultados y no específicamente donde corresponden.

```py
    import concurrent.futures
    import pandapower as pp
    import pandapower.networks as pn
    import time
    
    net = pn.case14()
    param_list = [10,20,30,40,50]
    
    
    # Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
    
    def fdp(red,p_mw):
        red.load.p_mw.at[3] = p_mw
        pp.runopp(red)
        return red.res_bus.lam_p  
      
    print("Running threaded:")
    threaded_start = time.time()
    
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        
        future_to_p = {executor.submit(fdp, net, p): p for p in param_list}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_p):
            p= future_to_p[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (p, exc))
            else:
                print(f'P:{p}\n{data.tolist()}')
    print("Threaded time:", time.time() - threaded_start)
```

Result first execution:

```
Running threaded:
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
P:50
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
P:40
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
P:20
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
P:10
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
P:30
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
Threaded time: 10.289913654327393
```

Result after first execution:

```
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
Running threaded:
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
P:20
[36.928335306007504, 38.56727922941338, 40.443172514058745, 40.72394443104987, 40.90622400559749, 41.46540572324214, 40.675081019595225, 40.41174715256963, 40.00281050735774, 40.07920802307382, 40.38560471085664, 40.38193763174398, 40.37963668287398, 40.552739535506646]
gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
P:30
[36.928335306007504, 38.56727922941338, 40.443172514058745, 40.72394443104987, 40.90622400559749, 41.46540572324214, 40.675081019595225, 40.41174715256963, 40.00281050735774, 40.07920802307382, 40.38560471085664, 40.38193763174398, 40.37963668287398, 40.552739535506646]
P:10
[36.928335306007504, 38.56727922941338, 40.443172514058745, 40.72394443104987, 40.90622400559749, 41.46540572324214, 40.675081019595225, 40.41174715256963, 40.00281050735774, 40.07920802307382, 40.38560471085664, 40.38193763174398, 40.37963668287398, 40.552739535506646]
P:40
[36.99051367937562, 38.62972152989315, 40.52523119429694, 40.80411871269535, 40.988284684904144, 41.54941541992989, 40.70451861749286, 40.47434804855512, 40.10859494962387, 40.158882354320575, 40.46021745533423, 40.45586106415878, 40.46147336798991, 40.63538923218931]
P:50
[37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
Threaded time: 5.970590829849243
```

Expected output:

```
    gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
    P: 10MW 
    [36.751272106399846, 38.38762996566227, 40.19506832628781, 40.430129260147005, 40.6234137762414, 41.2329955341445, 40.58851960709539, 40.22088592382624, 39.70638081851565, 39.78493232181634, 40.19846080489043, 40.19658795616762, 40.19163521434265, 40.34719067188158]
    gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
    P: 20MW 
    [36.85372545393822, 38.491904324526544, 40.34131262933125, 40.61232778016679, 40.79622873797999, 41.366262933523764, 40.63911029771148, 40.33365020295586, 39.877037015925644, 39.967766585867494, 40.302060961496764, 40.29918919390446, 40.29206912477938, 40.46060120186742]
    gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
    P: 30MW 
    [36.928335306007504, 38.56727922941338, 40.443172514058745, 40.72394443104987, 40.90622400559749, 41.46540572324214, 40.675081019595225, 40.41174715256963, 40.00281050735774, 40.07920802307382, 40.38560471085664, 40.38193763174398, 40.37963668287398, 40.552739535506646]
    gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
    P: 40MW 
    [36.99051367937562, 38.62972152989315, 40.52523119429694, 40.80411871269535, 40.988284684904144, 41.54941541992989, 40.70451861749286, 40.47434804855512, 40.10859494962387, 40.158882354320575, 40.46021745533423, 40.45586106415878, 40.46147336798991, 40.63538923218931]

    gen vm_pu > bus max_vm_pu for gens [2 3]. Setting bus limit for these gens.
    P: 50MW 
    [37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
```

Comment: Al ser hilos cada uno se ejecuta por su cuenta y cada uno tiene un tiempo de finalizaron distinto

Comment: @christian Si, precisamente el uso que pretendo darle a los Subprocesos es ejecutar en paralelo la misma función con diferentes valores sin importar el tiempo de ejecución sin embargo a lo que me refiero en mi problema es que a la función fdp le paso como parámetro un valor entero de p, y al ejecutar los pool de Threads imprimo en pantalla ese valor de p y la respuesta que corresponde a ese valor no corresponde sino que por ejemplo una misma respuesta es impresa para diferentes valores de p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### El problema

Efectivamente, hay un problema porque los hilos comparten una variable y por tanto los resultados de un hilo pisan a los de otro.

La variable que comparten es la que creas aquí:

```
net = pn.case14()
```

Esa variable es una referencia a un objeto creado por `pandapower`, que pasas como parámetro a la función:

```
def fdp(red,p_mw):
    red.load.p_mw.at[3] = p_mw
    pp.runopp(red)
    return red.res_bus.lam_p
```

El parámetro `red` se convierte en una referencia al mismo objeto, por lo que todos los hilos están operando sobre un mismo objeto al final.

Podemos comprobar que el problema desaparece si en lugar de pasar `red` como parámetro lo creas directamente dentro de esa función:

```
def fdp(red,p_mw):
    red = pn.case14()
    red.load.p_mw.at[3] = p_mw
    pp.runopp(red)
    return red.res_bus.lam_p
```

por tanto tenemos ya una pista para tratar de resolverlo.

### La solución

La función debería trabajar con una copia del objeto `net`, en lugar de con una referencia. Por desgracia en Python el paso de parámetros es siempre por referencia. Lo que podemos hacer es crear una copia de ese objeto dentro de la función.

Esto no es trivial, pues desconocemos los campos y la implementación interna de ese objeto, y si contiene a su vez referencias a otros objetos que haya que copiar (y parece que es así, pues el modelo de una red en pandapower contiene mucha información en su interior)

Por suerte tenemos el paquete `copy` que provee la función `deepcopy()` que se ocupará de hacer esa copia "profunda" (es decir, copiará también todos los objetos internos referenciados desde él).

Basta por tanto el siguiente añadido:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def fdp(red,p_mw):
    red = deepcopy(red)
    red.load.p_mw.at[3] = p_mw
    pp.runopp(red)
    return red.res_bus.lam_p
```

Para verificar el funcionamiento, voy a modificar también el bucle que lanza los trabajos al pool para que, en lugar de imprimir los resultados, los vaya almacenando en un diccionario:

```
print("Running threaded:")
threaded_start = time.time()

results = {}
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:   
    future_to_p = {executor.submit(fdp, net, p): p for p in param_list}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_p):
        p = future_to_p[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (p, exc))
        else:
            results[p] = data.to_list()
print("Threaded time:", time.time() - threaded_start)
```

Al terminar podemos imprimir el diccionario ordenando las claves para que salga primero 10, luego 20, etc.. con independencia del orden en que fueron terminando los hilos.

```
for p, r in sorted(results.items()):
  print(p, r)
```

Se obtiene:

```
10 [36.75127210639647, 38.38762996565819, 40.19506832628121, 40.430129260138926, 40.62341377623475, 41.23299553413959, 40.588519607093225, 40.22088592382141, 39.7063808185101, 39.7849323218095, 40.19846080488636, 40.19658795616364, 40.191635214338646, 40.347190671876646]
20 [36.85372545395841, 38.4919043245477, 40.34131262936431, 40.61232778021851, 40.79622873802595, 41.36626293354906, 40.63911029772222, 40.333650202981374, 39.87703701595878, 39.967766585919684, 40.30206096151179, 40.29918919391925, 40.29206912478943, 40.460601201883684]
30 [36.92833530600595, 38.56727922941147, 40.44317251405546, 40.72394443104559, 40.906224005594055, 41.465405723239954, 40.675081019594245, 40.41174715256742, 40.00281050735503, 40.07920802307006, 40.385604710854984, 40.381937631742424, 40.3796366828724, 40.5527395355045]
40 [36.990513679376, 38.62972152989373, 40.52523119429794, 40.80411871269643, 40.98828468490487, 41.54941541993041, 40.704518617493136, 40.474348048555726, 40.10859494962457, 40.15888235432138, 40.46021745533472, 40.455861064159215, 40.461473367990486, 40.63538923219006]
50 [37.052582825664956, 38.6920841468403, 40.60745702352431, 40.88440551971115, 41.07048955890086, 41.63367715315241, 40.733931553511496, 40.53692123467742, 40.21453418920852, 40.23866161530852, 40.534944260091955, 40.52988248975574, 40.5435133738319, 40.71825168461845]
```

## Bonus

Se puede verificar que la solución es correcta si la comparamos con la esperada, que has dado en la pregunta:

```
expected = {
10: [36.751272106399846, 38.38762996566227, 40.19506832628781, 40.430129260147005, 40.6234137762414, 41.2329955341445, 40.58851960709539, 40.22088592382624, 39.70638081851565, 39.78493232181634, 40.19846080489043, 40.19658795616762, 40.19163521434265, 40.34719067188158],
20: [36.85372545393822, 38.491904324526544, 40.34131262933125, 40.61232778016679, 40.79622873797999, 41.366262933523764, 40.63911029771148, 40.33365020295586, 39.877037015925644, 39.967766585867494, 40.302060961496764, 40.29918919390446, 40.29206912477938, 40.46060120186742],
30: [36.928335306007504, 38.56727922941338, 40.443172514058745, 40.72394443104987, 40.90622400559749, 41.46540572324214, 40.675081019595225, 40.41174715256963, 40.00281050735774, 40.07920802307382, 40.38560471085664, 40.38193763174398, 40.37963668287398, 40.552739535506646],
40: [36.99051367937562, 38.62972152989315, 40.52523119429694, 40.80411871269535, 40.988284684904144, 41.54941541992989, 40.70451861749286, 40.47434804855512, 40.10859494962387, 40.158882354320575, 40.46021745533423, 40.45586106415878, 40.46147336798991, 40.63538923218931],
50: [37.05258282566508, 38.692084146840514, 40.607457023524645, 40.884405519711464, 41.07048955890102, 41.63367715315253, 40.7339315535116, 40.53692123467765, 40.214534189208756, 40.23866161530872, 40.534944260092104, 40.52988248975587, 40.543513373832106, 40.71825168461873]
}
```

Pero ya que no será *exactamente* igual debido a errores de redondeo de punto flotante, podemos usar la función `numpy.isclose()` para la comparación:

```
import numpy as np

for p, r in sorted(results.items()):
  if np.isclose(r, expected[p]).all():
    print(p, "Ok")
```

Salida:

```
10 Ok
20 Ok
30 Ok
40 Ok
50 Ok
```

### Nota adicional sobre rendimiento

La solución multihilo te dará ganancia de tiempo si lo ejecutas en una plataforma con múltiples núcleos, y quizás ni así, pues depende de cómo esté implementada la librería `pandapower`.

Ejecutando el programa en Google Colab, el mejor tiempo lo obtengo para 1 solo hilo, a pesar de que supuestamente esta plataforma usa 2 cores. Esto apunta a que `pandapower` contiene código que usa intensivamente la CPU desde el lenguaje Python, a diferencia de otras bibliotecas como `pandas` o `numpy` que tienen la parte que mayor CPU consume escrita en C.

La diferencia es relevante porque Python tiene en el proceso del intérprete un "cerrojo" (Global Intepreter Lock o GIL) que impide que dos hilos dentro del mismo proceso ejecuten código pyton a la vez. Les obliga a ir "turnándose" de modo que un hilo ejecuta una instrucción, después otro hilo ejecuta otra, etc. Y esto *incluso si cada hilo está en un núcleo diferente*. De hecho está estudiado que el rendimiento debido al GIL puede llegar a ser mucho menor que si hubiera un solo hilo. Las partes que están escritas en C, en cambio, no se ven afectadas por el GIL.

Si en vez de multihilo utilizas **multiproceso**, el GIL ya no interfiere (porque cada proceso tiene su propio GIL, y un solo hilo). Ya que cada proceso se ejecuta además en un espacio de memoria separado en el que no puede compartir con otros procesos, el paso de parámetros se hace en realidad a través de sockets unix. Esto impone una pequeña penalización en la comunicación entre procesos, pero que se puede ver compensada con el mejor aprovechamiento de los núcleos de procesamiento.

Como efecto secundario y ventajoso en este caso, el paso de parámetros causa que el otro proceso reciba una copia, por lo que podemos ya omitir el `deepcopy()`.

Basta cambiar  `ThreadPoolExecutor` por `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

#### Medidas de rendimiento

```
Con ThreadPool:
  2 hilos   -----> 8.75s
  1 hilo    -----> 5.97s
Con ProcessPool:
  2 procesos   --> 5.45s
  1 proceso   ---> 5.99s

Sin concurrencia:
  iterar normal -> 5.93s
```

Conclusiones: la versión multiproceso con 2 procesos (en una máquina de 2 núcleos) es la más rápida, pero por muy poco. Apenas compensa con respecto a la versión sin concurrencia. Naturalmente en una máquina de 8 cores y usando 8 workers, la diferencia debería ser notable.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución...Si es verdad evaluando los  tiempos de ejecución con 1 hilo son mejores, y el ordenador en el que lo probé posee 8 núcleos...cual podría ser una posible causa

Comment: @ChristianRueda He ampliado la respuesta explicando por qué la solución multihilo es más lenta que una solución no concurrente, y dando una posible solución (multiproceso) y medidas de rendimiento que he tomado.